# Derivative of $-\cot^{-1} (x/5) - \cos^{-1} (3-x/2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[This is the original Problem where I am supposed to find the point P to maximize the value of theta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czrNg.png)

I am trying to get the derivative of this equation here

$$\pi -\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(3-x\right)}{2}\right)$$

This is what I got
$$\frac{5}{x^2+25}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+6x-5}}$$

But this is the answer
$$\frac{3\left(x^2-10+5\right)}{\left(x^2+25\right)\left(x^2-6x+13\right)}$$

which I don't understand how it got there and I am supposed to set it to $0$ to get
$$x = 5-2\sqrt{5}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta=\cot\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)$, not $\cos\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)$.
So your $\pi -\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)$ should be
$$\pi -\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: From there how do I get x=5−2√5 ?

Comment: @Titor: Set the numerator $3(x^2-10x+5)$ to zero...